# Unable to assign value to function in Object Oriented Programming, Array

Tags: java, arrays, function, oop, netbeans

I am using Java Netbeans. I am new to Object Oriented Programming (OOPG). This is my first assignment and I am having some issues with some calculations within a function. I have referred to lab exercises. But I still failed to spot the mistake. Below is my code:

//Student Class

```
package student;

public class Student {

  private String studentName
  private int assignmentMarks;
  private int practicalMarks;
  private int examMarks;
  private double overallMarks;
  private String finalGrade;

  public Student(){
  }

  public setStudent (String sName, int aMarks, int pMarks, int eMarks, double oMarks, String fGrade){
    studentName = sName;
    assignmentMarks = aMarks;
    practicalMarks = pMarks;
    examMarks = eMarks;
    overallMarks = oMarks;
    finalGrade = fGrade;
  }

  //Setters
  public void setStudentName (String sn) {
    studentName = sn;
  }

  public setAssignmentMarks (int am) {
    assignmentMarks = am;
  }

  public setPracticalMarks (int pm) {
    practicalMarks = pm;
  }

  public setExamMarks (int em) {
    examMarks = em;
  }

  public setOverallMarks (om) {
    overallMarks = om;
  }

  public setFinalGrade (fg) {
    finalGrade = fg;
  }

  //Getters
  public String getStudentName() {
    return studentName;
  }

  public int getAssignmentMarks() {
    return assignmentMarks;
  }

  public int getPracticalMarks() {
    return practicalMarks;
  }

  public int getExamMarks() {
    return examMarks;
  }

  public double getOverallMarks() {
    return overallMarks;
  }

  public String getFinalGrade() {
    return finalGrade;
  }

  //method to calculate overall marks
  //assignment 25% + practical 25% + exam 50%
  public double calOverallMarks (int am, int pm, int em){
    double overallMarks = ( ((am/100)*25) + ((pm/100)*25) + ((em/100)*50) );
    return overallMarks;
  }

  //method to calculate final grade by overall marks
  public String calFinalGrade (double om) {
    if (om >=90 ) {
      return "A";
    } else if (om >=70) {
        return "B";
    } else if (om >=50) {
        return "C";
    } else {
        return ""F";
    }
  }

  //method to display overall and finalgrade score for input
  public void displayMarks(){
    System.out.println("Overall Marks: " + overallMarks);
    System.out.println("Final Grade: " + finalGrade);
  }

}
```

//Student Client Class

```
package student;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class StudentClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
      String studentName;
      int assignmentMarks;
      int practicalMarks;
      int examMarks;
      double overallMarks =0;
      String finalGrade;
      int option;
      int studentIndex=0;

      Student[] studentList = new Student[10];
      System.out.println("MENU- Select 2 to enter student details")
      option = sc.nextInt();

         if (option == 2) {
             studentIndex++;
             studentList [studentIndex] = new Student();
             System.out.print("Student Name: ");
             studentName = sc.nextLine();
             System.out.print("Assignment Marks: ");
             assignmentMarks = sc.nextInt();
             System.out.print("Practical Marks: ");
             practicalMarks = sc.nextInt();
             System.out.print("Exam Marks: ");
             examMarks = sc.nextInt();

             overallMarks = studentList[studentIndex].calOverallMarks(assignmentMarks, practicalMarks, examMarks);

             finalGrade = studentList[studentIndex].calFinalGrade(overallMarks);

             studentList[studentIndex].setStudent(studentName, assignmentMarks, practicalMarks, examMarks, overallMarks, finalGrade);

             studentList[studentIndex].writeOutput();
    }

  }
```

The output I received after running the student client class is :

```
Student Name: Pete
Assignment Marks: 50
Practical Marks: 95
Exam Marks: 85
Overall Marks: 0.0
Final Grade: F
```

May I know which part have I made a mistake in?

Thank you for the help given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you made the classic mistake of performing int division and expecting a floating point result.

change

```
double overallMarks = ( ((am/100)*25) + ((pm/100)*25) + ((em/100)*50) );
```

to

```
double overallMarks = ( ((am/100.0)*25) + ((pm/100.0)*25) + ((em/100.0)*50) );
```

This will force floating point division.

In addition, instead of passing all the properties to `setStudent`, why don't you pass them to a constructor? That's a more common practice in Java.

So instead of

```
studentList [studentIndex] = new Student();
...
studentList[studentIndex].setStudent(studentName, assignmentMarks, practicalMarks, examMarks, overallMarks, finalGrade);
```

I would write

```
....
studentList [studentIndex] = new Student(studentName, assignmentMarks, practicalMarks, examMarks, overallMarks, finalGrade);
```

This requires changing your Student constructor.

Comment: I tend to write `x * (1/100d)` instead of `x/100.0` as it performs a multiplication and is more readable for me. As for the author it becomes `double overallMarks = am * (25/100d) + pm  * (25/100d) + em * (50/100d)`

Comment: Thank you @Eran, I did not realize it will be affected. Your solution solved my issue. :)

Comment: @BinkanSalaryman yes I will, I'm waiting for the timer to expire to I can accept Eran's answer :)